# Redirect does not work through mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why does not work this regex? The general problem appears after simbol "?", Probable several options, but could not solve the problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portfolio.php?id=(.*?)$ /index.php?page_id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` pattern, that is used for matching `REQUEST_URI` only. You will need a `RewriteCond` for that. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio\.php$ /index.php?page_id=%1 [L,QSA]
```